# How to get newly created entity id from interceptor

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm extending hibernate EmptyInterceptor and I want to log a newly created entity id. In the onSave method I get the entity without the auto generated id. what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

API `EmptyInterceptor` :

```
boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
```

So you get the id via the argument.

Comment: I'm currently working with onSave but in a new entity the id is null.

Comment: Do you use the `Object entity` parameter or the `Serializable id` parameter?

Comment: Are you sure the `Interceptor` is called?